# Incorrect format date in java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, calendar

I get some trouble with my work.
It is like this : 
In my proj , I got a strange exception(below),I check the code, I found It is a entityManager.flush() method throw out the exception.I find It may be a entityManager.persist() method get some trouble. our customer told me this exception occurs when run a job, and when run the job again,It successed.I think this should not be a problem with code,because if that ,It will not successed when run the job twice.
I think if there exist some bug when Calendar.addMonth() or Calendar.addDay().
I can't get clear.
anybody have ever see this ? why there we get a incorrect format date ?

```
2013-07-11 20:35:50,504 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] Batch entry 0 insert into statementitem (account_accountid, amountDue, amountPaid, createDate, financiatransactiontype_transactiontypeid, information, pending, periodEnd, periodStart, relatedStatement, sequenceNumber, statementitems_statementid, verification_verificationid, statementItemId) values (NULL, '15.0', '0.0', NULL, 'Statement fee', 'DIRECT_DEBIT_STATEMENT_FEE', '0', '0008-07-28 00:00:00.000000 +01:00:00', '20137037-04-08 00:00:00.000000 +02:00:00', '1043', '3', '140034086', '140034090', '140034091') was aborted. Call getNextException to see the cause.
2013-07-11 20:35:50,504 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] ERROR: timestamp out of range: "20137037-04-08 00:00:00.000000 +02:00:00"
2013-07-11 20:35:50,505 ERROR [org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener] Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:100)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.prepareBatchStatement(AbstractBatcher.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2252)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2688)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:79)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:279)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1027)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.jpa.tx.TransactionScopedEntityManager.flush(TransactionScopedEntityManager.java:216)
    at greenback.backend.dao.beans.PerformanceDaoBean.updateAccount(PerformanceDaoBean.java:707)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor765.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.java:69)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:73)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor711.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:72)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1529847521.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1529847521.java)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1529847521.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1529847521.java)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1529847521.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1529847521.java)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1529847521.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1529847521.java)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy.invokeInCallerTx(TxPolicy.java:126)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxInterceptor$Required.invoke(TxInterceptor.java:194)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPropagationInterceptor.invoke(TxPropagationInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptorv2.invoke(RoleBasedAuthorizationInterceptorv2.java:201)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:186)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.ENCPropagationInterceptor.invoke(ENCPropagationInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:176)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.session.SessionSpecContainer.invoke(SessionSpecContainer.java:216)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:207)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.proxy.impl.handler.session.SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.invoke(SessionProxyInvocationHandlerBase.java:164)
    at $Proxy1103.updateAccount(Unknown Source)
    at greenback.backend.services.statement.StatementServiceBean.createStatementWithAccountNumberBatch(StatementServiceBean.java:589)
    at greenback.backend.services.statement.StatementServiceBean.createStatement(StatementServiceBean.java:308)
    at greenback.backend.services.statement.StatementServiceBean.createStatement(StatementServiceBean.java:162)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)
    at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(EJBContainerInvocationWrapper.java:69)
    at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor$InvocationContext.proceed(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:138)
    at greenback.backend.security.AuthenticationInterceptor.intercept(AuthenticationInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor339.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into statementitem (account_accountid, amountDue, amountPaid, createDate, financiatransactiontype_transactiontypeid, information, pending, periodEnd, periodStart, relatedStatement, sequenceNumber, statementitems_statementid, verification_verificationid, statementItemId) values (NULL, '15.0', '0.0', NULL, 'Statement fee', 'DIRECT_DEBIT_STATEMENT_FEE', '0', '0008-07-28 00:00:00.000000 +01:00:00', '20137037-04-08 00:00:00.000000 +02:00:00', '1043', '3', '140034086', '140034090', '140034091') was aborted. Call getNextException to see the cause.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement$BatchResultHandler.handleError(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2569)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1796)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:407)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeBatch(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:2708)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedStatement.executeBatch(WrappedStatement.java:774)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 362 more
2013-07-11 20:35:50,584 ERROR [org.jboss.aspects.tx.TxPolicy] javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
```

Comment: Wat happens when you try to execute this query by yourself? (the one that is displayed in the stack trace)

Comment: can you past your java code? 20137037 this date is an extrange data i supose. For example with Calendar.MONTH you get a month that is not the real month, you must plus one to the month because started to count from month 0...

Comment: @JB Nizet the postgres also show timestamp out of range when I run that query.So I think the sql must grnerate a incorrect canlendar.

Comment: @Deckard27 ,as I said before , the exception occurs when the code entityManager.flush(). do you think my code get sth wrong when Calendar.addMonth() ? but rerun is successed.

Answer (score 0):

In JPA entity class, what kind of TemporalType do you use?
Try this:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: I did not specify any annotation. and I can not reproduce this issue.I  also can not ensure if it is this reason.